# JNLP as a Applet in HTML page

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, next-generation-plugin

I'm trying to run my JNLP within an HTML page, but the java plugin does not run the JNLP, runs only the Applet.

Here is my code:

```
<applet width="800" height="500" codebase="http://127.0.0.1:8888/applets/"
    code="br.com.app.server.utils.CompatibilityApplet"
    archive="CompatibilityApplet.jar">
            <param name="jnlp_ref" value="http://127.0.0.1:8888/applets/testehellojws.jnlp">
</applet>
```

Thanks.

[EDIT]

An example:

http://java.sun.com/javase/ja/6/ea/6u10/plugin2/jnlp/CompatibilityApplet.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="http://127.0.0.1:8888/applets/" href="testehellojws.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>App Hello</title>
        <vendor>My App Jnlp.</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/Home.html"/>
        <description>My App Jnlp</description>
        <description kind="short">Appr</description>
        <icon href="images/icone.jpg"/>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="hello.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="br.com.app.server.HelloJWS"></application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

> Please edit your question and just let me know it is edited.

OK

> Did you miss the part about the documentBase?

I didn't.

> I would recommend removing the space in the applet name attribute.

Done

> Can you run any other JNLP embedded applets? E.G. the small (sand-boxed) GIFanim applet at my site?

Yes

> What info. do you get reported from here?

java.vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. 
java.version: 1.6.0_26
os.name: Windows 7
os.version: 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking on a related post, I decided to test the tag

```
<OBJECT>
```

.
I thought that this would not work with JNLP, so we had tested before.
After changing

```
<APPLET>
```

to

```
<OBJECT>
```

and referencing my jnlp file as a parameter, it worked!
The browser ignores the code and archive parameters and run my JNLP.

thanks.

Comment: I added a comment (now deleted) before noticing this answer.  It makes me more sure that it was a caching problem.  Changing it to the `object` element probably fooled the JRE into thinking it had to download it fresh.  But don't settle for that, use [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) to write the correct applet (/object/embed ..whatever) element.

Comment: I will try it. I don't know if it's possible to use it with GWT. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 2):

```
<application-desc main-class="br.com.app.server.HelloJWS"></application-desc>
```

That is the descriptor for a Java application (as opposed to an applet).  For an applet, use something more like..

```
<applet-desc main-class="br.com.app.server.HelloJWS"></applet-desc>
```

Note:

1. Even that is not a correct descriptor for an applet, which must explicitly state a `documentBase`, `name`, `width` & `height`.  See the [applet-desc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jws/developersguide/syntax.html#applet_desc) section of the JNLP File Syntax for more details.
2. It must (of course) be an applet.  It is not possible to 'embed' an application into a web page using this technique.
3. **JNLP and the Java Plug-In (required for both applets and web start) was deprecated and *removed from the API* in Java 9.**

Answer (score 1):

Your `jnlp_ref` should probably be an absolute URI, e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8888/applets/testehellojws.jnlp`

Also there is a stray space at the start of your `code` value (though this is probably not the cause of your problem.)

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove [archive="CompatibilityApplet.jar"]